# Paging library call just to LoadInitial after swipe up to refresh, and doesn't call to LoadAfter

Tags: android, rx-java, paging, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to create app using Paging library + RxJava, all works fine, it load data from backend and insert it in my Recyclerview, and when i scroll down LoadAfter load next pages normaly, my problem is when i swipe up to refrech data using SwipeLayoutRefrech it invalidate data source and it call just to LoadInitial (load just 20 first item), and LoadAfter doesn't called at all, i spent much time on it but still no solution.

Here is my Data Source Factory :

```
public class GalleryPhotosDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory<Integer, GalleryPhotosItems> {

private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

private MutableLiveData<GalleryPhotosDataSource> DataSourceMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();


/**
 * Create a DataSource.
 * <p>
 * The DataSource should invalidate itself if the snapshot is no longer valid. If a
 * DataSource becomes invalid, the only way to query more data is to create a new DataSource
 * from the Factory.
 * <p>
 * {@link } for example will construct a new PagedList and DataSource
 * when the current DataSource is invalidated, and pass the new PagedList through the
 * {@code LiveData<PagedList>} to observers.
 *
 * @return the new DataSource.
 */

public GalleryPhotosDataSourceFactory(CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
    this.compositeDisposable = compositeDisposable;
}

@Override
public DataSource<Integer, GalleryPhotosItems> create() {
    GalleryPhotosDataSource galleryPhotosDataSource = new GalleryPhotosDataSource(compositeDisposable);
    DataSourceMutableLiveData.postValue(galleryPhotosDataSource);
    return galleryPhotosDataSource;
}

@NonNull
public MutableLiveData<GalleryPhotosDataSource> getDataSourceLiveData() {
    return DataSourceMutableLiveData ;
}
}
```

And my class Data Source for load data from my server :

```
public class GalleryPhotosDataSource extends ItemKeyedDataSource<Integer, GalleryPhotosItems> {

public static final String TAG = "GalleryPhotosDataSource";

private ApiService apiService;

private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

private MutableLiveData<NetworkState> networkState = new MutableLiveData<>();

private MutableLiveData<NetworkState> initialLoad = new MutableLiveData<>();

/**
 * Keep Completable reference for the retry event
 */
private Completable retryCompletable;

GalleryPhotosDataSource(CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
    this.apiService = Client.createAppService();
    this.compositeDisposable = compositeDisposable;
}

public void retry() {
    if (retryCompletable != null) {
        compositeDisposable.add(retryCompletable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(() -> {
                }, throwable -> Timber.e(throwable.getMessage())));
    }
}




/**
 * Load initial data.
 * <p>
 * This method is called first to initialize a PagedList with data. If it's possible to count
 * the items that can be loaded by the DataSource, it's recommended to pass the loaded data to
 * the callback via the three-parameter
 * {@link LoadInitialCallback#onResult(List, int, int)}. This enables PagedLists
 * presenting data from this source to display placeholders to represent unloaded items.
 * <p>
 * {@link LoadInitialParams#requestedInitialKey} and {@link LoadInitialParams#requestedLoadSize}
 * are hints, not requirements, so they may be altered or ignored. Note that ignoring the
 * {@code requestedInitialKey} can prevent subsequent PagedList/DataSource pairs from
 * initializing at the same location. If your data source never invalidates (for example,
 * loading from the network without the network ever signalling that old data must be reloaded),
 * it's fine to ignore the {@code initialLoadKey} and always start from the beginning of the
 * data set.
 *
 * @param params   Parameters for initial load, including initial key and requested size.
 * @param callback Callback that receives initial load data.
 */
@Override
public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<GalleryPhotosItems> callback) {
    // update network states.
    // we also provide an initial load state to the listeners so that the UI can know when the
    // very first list is loaded.
    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING);
    initialLoad.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING);

    //get the initial users from the api
    compositeDisposable.add(apiService.getPhotosGallery(1, 5, -1, params.requestedLoadSize).subscribe(galleryPhotosItemses -> {
                // clear retry since last request succeeded
                setRetry(null);
                networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                initialLoad.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                callback.onResult(galleryPhotosItemses);
            },
            throwable -> {
                // keep a Completable for future retry
                setRetry(() -> loadInitial(params, callback));
                NetworkState error = NetworkState.error(throwable.getMessage());
                // publish the error
                networkState.postValue(error);
                initialLoad.postValue(error);
            }));
}

/**
 * Load list data after the key specified in {@link LoadParams#key LoadParams.key}.
 * <p>
 * It's valid to return a different list size than the page size if it's easier, e.g. if your
 * backend defines page sizes. It is generally safer to increase the number loaded than reduce.
 * <p>
 * Data may be passed synchronously during the loadAfter method, or deferred and called at a
 * later time. Further loads going down will be blocked until the callback is called.
 * <p>
 * If data cannot be loaded (for example, if the request is invalid, or the data would be stale
 * and inconsistent, it is valid to call {@link #invalidate()} to invalidate the data source,
 * and prevent further loading.
 *
 * @param params   Parameters for the load, including the key to load after, and requested size.
 * @param callback Callback that receives loaded data.
 */
@Override
public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<GalleryPhotosItems> callback) {
    // set network value to loading.
    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING);

    //get the users from the api after id
    compositeDisposable.add(apiService.getPhotosGallery(1, 5, params.key-1, params.requestedLoadSize).subscribe(galleryPhotosItemses -> {
                // clear retry since last request succeeded
                setRetry(null);
                networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                callback.onResult(galleryPhotosItemses);
},
            throwable -> {
                // keep a Completable for future retry photos_user/5/1534161047_1534160953579.jpg
                setRetry(() -> loadAfter(params, callback));
                // publish the error
                networkState.postValue(NetworkState.error(throwable.getMessage()));
            }));

}

/**
 * Load list data before the key specified in {@link LoadParams#key LoadParams.key}.
 * <p>
 * It's valid to return a different list size than the page size if it's easier, e.g. if your
 * backend defines page sizes. It is generally safer to increase the number loaded than reduce.
 * <p>
 * <p class="note"><strong>Note:</strong> Data returned will be prepended just before the key
 * passed, so if you vary size, ensure that the last item is adjacent to the passed key.
 * <p>
 * Data may be passed synchronously during the loadBefore method, or deferred and called at a
 * later time. Further loads going up will be blocked until the callback is called.
 * <p>
 * If data cannot be loaded (for example, if the request is invalid, or the data would be stale
 * and inconsistent, it is valid to call {@link #invalidate()} to invalidate the data source,
 * and prevent further loading.
 *
 * @param params   Parameters for the load, including the key to load before, and requested size.
 * @param callback Callback that receives loaded data.
 */
@Override
public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<GalleryPhotosItems> callback) {

}

/**
 * Return a key associated with the given item.
 * <p>
 * If your ItemKeyedDataSource is loading from a source that is sorted and loaded by a unique
 * integer ID, you would return {@code item.getID()} here. This key can then be passed to
 * {@link #loadBefore(LoadParams, LoadCallback)} or
 * {@link #loadAfter(LoadParams, LoadCallback)} to load additional items adjacent to the item
 * passed to this function.
 * <p>
 * If your key is more complex, such as when you're sorting by name, then resolving collisions
 * with integer ID, you'll need to return both. In such a case you would use a wrapper class,
 * such as {@code Pair<String, Integer>} or, in Kotlin,
 * {@code data class Key(val name: String, val id: Int)}
 *
 * @param item Item to get the key from.
 * @return Key associated with given item.
 */
@NonNull
@Override
public Integer getKey(@NonNull GalleryPhotosItems item) {
    return item.getPhoto_id();
}

@NonNull
public MutableLiveData<NetworkState> getNetworkState() {
    return networkState;
}

@NonNull
public MutableLiveData<NetworkState> getInitialLoad() {
    return initialLoad;
}

private void setRetry(final Action action) {
    if (action == null) {
        this.retryCompletable = null;
    } else {
        this.retryCompletable = Completable.fromAction(action);
    }
}
}
```

My ViewModel :

```
public class GalleryPhotosViewModel extends ViewModel {

public LiveData<PagedList<GalleryPhotosItems>> photosList;

private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

private static final int pageSize = 10;

private GalleryPhotosDataSourceFactory photosDataSourceFactory;

public GalleryPhotosViewModel() {
    photosDataSourceFactory = new GalleryPhotosDataSourceFactory(compositeDisposable);

    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(pageSize)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(pageSize * 2)
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .build();

    photosList = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(photosDataSourceFactory, config).build();


}

public void retry() {
    photosDataSourceFactory.getDataSourceLiveData().getValue().retry();
}

public void refresh() {
    photosDataSourceFactory.getDataSourceLiveData().getValue().invalidate();
}

public LiveData<NetworkState> getNetworkState() {
    return Transformations.switchMap(photosDataSourceFactory.getDataSourceLiveData(), GalleryPhotosDataSource::getNetworkState);
}

public LiveData<NetworkState> getRefreshState() {
    return Transformations.switchMap(photosDataSourceFactory.getDataSourceLiveData(), GalleryPhotosDataSource::getInitialLoad);
}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();
    compositeDisposable.dispose();
}
}
```

And finally its my fragment for initAdapter and SwipeRefreshLayout :

```
public class AbonnesFragment extends Fragment  implements RetryCallback{

@BindView(usersSwipeRefreshLayout)
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

@BindView(R.id.usersRecyclerView)
RecyclerView usersRecyclerView;

@BindView(R.id.errorMessageTextView)
TextView errorMessageTextView;

@BindView(R.id.retryLoadingButton)
Button retryLoadingButton;

@BindView(R.id.loadingProgressBar)
ProgressBar loadingProgressBar;

private GalleryPhotosViewModel viewModel;

private GalleryPhotosAdapter Adapter;

View rootView;

public AbonnesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryPhotosViewModel.class);
    initAdapter();
    initSwipeToRefresh();

    return rootView;
}



private void initAdapter() {
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch(Adapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                case R.layout.gallery_photos_items:
                    return 1;
                case R.layout.item_network_state:
                    return 3;
                default:
                    return -1;
            }
        }
    });

    Adapter = new GalleryPhotosAdapter(this);
    usersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    usersRecyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);

    viewModel.photosList.observe(this, Adapter::submitList);
    viewModel.getNetworkState().observe(this, Adapter::setNetworkState);
}

/**
 * Init swipe to refresh and enable pull to refresh only when there are items in the adapter
 */
private void initSwipeToRefresh() {
   viewModel.getRefreshState().observe(this, networkState -> {
        if (networkState != null) {
            if (Adapter.getCurrentList() != null) {
                if (Adapter.getCurrentList().size() > 0) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(networkState.getStatus() == NetworkState.LOADING.getStatus());
                } else {
                    setInitialLoadingState(networkState);
                }
            } else {
                setInitialLoadingState(networkState);
            }
        }
    });
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> viewModel.refresh());

}

/**
 * Show the current network state for the first load when the user list
 * in the adapter is empty and disable swipe to scroll at the first loading
 *
 * @param networkState the new network state
 */
private void setInitialLoadingState(NetworkState networkState) {
    //error message
    errorMessageTextView.setVisibility(networkState.getMessage() != null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    if (networkState.getMessage() != null) {
        errorMessageTextView.setText(networkState.getMessage());
    }

    //loading and retry
    retryLoadingButton.setVisibility(networkState.getStatus() == Status.FAILED ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(networkState.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    if (networkState.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS){
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.retryLoadingButton)
void retryInitialLoading() {
    viewModel.retry();

}

@Override
public void retry() {
    viewModel.retry();

}
}
```

I hope to find someone could help me, Thanks

Comment: i have exactly the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a reported and fixed bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113122599

Fixed in 2.1.0-alpha01

> Fixed a case where an extremely small initial load size together with unchanged data would result in no further loading b/113122599

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes